# Unable to access Elastic Beanstalk (single instance) from custom domain HTTPS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Greetings SO community,

I am attempting to configure my single-instance Elastic Beanstalk application to use a custom domain and HTTPS. Both the custom domain and SSL certificate were obtained from a third-party and uses their DNS servers (rather than Route 53).

I have added the `.ebextensions/https-instance-securitygroup.config` per AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html) as well as the files for Node application (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-nodejs.html). The only difference in the last step is that I did not create a `.ebextensions/https-instance.config` file as I am pushing my code to GitHub and using CodePipeline to build my code. So, the `https.conf` and certificates were manually created and uploaded to the EC2 instance.

Also, I have checked my instance's inbound rules to ensure that 80 & 443 are open on the EB instance and for the associated security group.

[image: Elastic Beanstalk EC2 Instance Inbound Rules]

**proxy.conf**

```
upstream nodejs {
  server 127.0.0.1:5000;
  keepalive 256;
}

server {
  listen 8080;

  if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
      set $year $1;
      set $month $2;
      set $day $3;
      set $hour $4;
  }
  access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  location / {
      proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
      proxy_set_header   Connection "";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  location /static {
      alias /var/app/current/client/build/static;
  }

}
```

**https.conf**

```
# HTTPS server

server {
  listen       443      ssl;
  server_name  localhost;

  ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  # For enhanced health reporting support, uncomment this block:

  #if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
  #    set $year $1;
  #    set $month $2;
  #    set $day $3;
  #    set $hour $4;
  #}
  #access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
  #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  location / {
          proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
          proxy_set_header   Connection "";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }
}
```

Comment: The "manually created" certs are self-signed certificates?

Comment: No. The certificates are from a CA. I just meant that they were uploaded to the EC2 instance manually rather than using the AWS-provided config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after rereading the AWS documentation for what felt like the hundredth time, I was finally able to resolve my issues. And because I wasn't strictly using the preferred method of using an `.ebextensions` folder, I had to fiddle with the Nginx proxy on the Elastic Beanstalk-created EC2 instance directly.

In short, I was missing the following section from my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`file:

```
location / {
   ### START MISSING ###
   set $redirect 0;
   if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
     set $redirect 1;
   }
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "ELB-HealthChecker") {
     set $redirect 0;
   }
   if ($redirect = 1) {
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }
   ### END OF MISSING ###

   proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
   proxy_set_header   Connection "";
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
   proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

This documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html

Specifically, This is a snippet from the NodeJS, default Nginx proxy config file: https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/nodejs/https-redirect-nodejs.config